# How can I change the color of class name during declaration of object for c++ in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext

Here I want to change the color for myClass and vector underlined in the screenshot. How can I do this?

[image: Please check this screenshot]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: In response to your question, there is no way to change the color of those items with the C++ syntax that ships with Sublime Text.